# Looking for midrash on the reason why Avraham bought Machpelah

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, abraham, parashat-chaye-sara

In Bereishit 23, Avraham buys Maarat HaMachpelah for four hundred shekels even though Ephron generously offers to give him the cave for free.

I recall there being a midrash that explains the reason that Avraham bought the cave instead of taking up Ephron's offer (something about so later no one could take it back), but I can't find it.

Could someone locate the midrash for me?

Comment: Hi Sarah. You are asking for the location of a specified Midrash and also you are asking for reasons for a certain action in Tanakh. Please [edit] to limit this to one question per post.

Comment: The Midrash can be found in Bereshit Rabbah 79:7. When the question is edited and I can answer, I'll post it up here with a translation.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it make more sense.

Comment: Avraham saw the cave glowing and realized that Adam and Chava were buried there and that is why he desired it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are thinking of Pirkei DiRabi Elazar chapter 35:

> אמ' לבני יבוס לקנות מהם את מערת המכפלה במכר טוב בזהב ובכתב לאחוזת קבר עולם

We see his intention to buy the cave to be kept as eternal grave and his usage of good gold to achieve that goal. But we also find him using a document for that same result.

A more complete quote, but still not the full story:

> ורץ להביא בן בקר וברח מלפניו בן הבקר ונכנס למערת המכפלה ונכנס אברהם אחריו ומצא שם אדם הראשון ועזרו שוכבים על המטות וישינים ונירות דולקות עליהן וריח טוב עליהם כריח ניחוח לפיכך חמד המערה לאחוזת קבר אמ' לבני יבוס לקנות מהם את מערת המכפלה במכר טוב בזהב ובכתב לאחוזת קבר עולם וכי יבוסים היו והלא חתיים היו אלא עיר יבוס נקרא יבוסים ולא קבלו האנשים עליהם התחיל כורע ומשתחוה אליהם שנ' וישתחו אברהם לפני עם הארץ אמרו אנו יודעים שעתיד הב"ה ליתן לך ולזרעך את כל הארצות האלה כרות עמנו שבועה שאין ישר' יורשים את עיר יבוס כי אם ברצונם ואח"כ קנה את המכפלה במכר זהב ובכתב עולם לאחוזת עולם וישמע אברהם אל עפרון מה עשו אנשי יבוס עשו צלמי נחשת והעמידו אותם ברחוב העיר וכתבו עליהם שבועת אברהם וכשבאו ישראל רץ להכנס בעיר היבוסי ולא היה יכול מפני ברית אברהם שנ' ואת היבוסי יושבי ירושלם לא הורישו בני ישראל

Comment: I'm also not sure how much we can read into this exchange. True his intention was the long lasting ownership and true these were the means he used, but we don't see how dependant the end result was upon these means.

Answer (score 0):

The midrash is located in Bereishit Rabbah 79:7, which states:

> וַיִּקֶּן אֶת חֶלְקַת הַשָּׂדֶה אֲשֶׁר נָטָה שָׁם אָהֳלוֹ וגו' בְּמֵאָה קְשִׂיטָה, אָמַר רַבִּי יוּדָן בַּר סִימוֹן זֶה אֶחָד מִשְׁלשָׁה מְקוֹמוֹת שֶׁאֵין אֻמּוֹת הָעוֹלָם יְכוֹלִין לְהוֹנוֹת אֶת יִשְׂרָאֵל לוֹמַר גְּזוּלִים הֵן בְּיֶדְכֶם, וְאֵלּוּ הֵן: מְעָרַת הַמַּכְפֵּלָה, וּבֵית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ, וּקְבוּרָתוֹ שֶׁל יוֹסֵף. מְעָרַת הַמַּכְפֵּלָה, דִּכְתִיב: וַיִּשְׁמַע אַבְרָהָם אֶל עֶפְרוֹן וַיִּשְׁקֹל אַבְרָהָם לְעֶפְרֹן, בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ, דִּכְתִיב: וַיִּתֵּן דָּוִיד לְאָרְנָן בַּמָּקוֹם וגו'. וּקְבוּרָתוֹ שֶׁל יוֹסֵף:

Rough translation:

Rabbi Yudan bar Simon brings three things that belong to Bnei Yisrael that no one can say they belong to someone else, and they are:

- Ma'arat HaMachpelah, as it says: "And Abraham listened to Ephron, and Abraham weighed out to Ephron the silver that he had named in the hearing of the sons of Heth, four hundred shekels of silver, accepted by the merchant." (Bereishit 23:16)
- The Beit HaMikdash, as it says: "And David gave to Ornan for the place shekels of gold weighing six hundred." (Divrei HaYamim I 21:15)
- The kever of Yosef, as it says: "And he bought the part of the field where he had pitched his tent from the sons of Hamor, the father of Shechem, for a hundred kesitas." (Bereishit 33:19)

It must be noted, however, that this midrash does not mention the *reason* Abraham purchased the field from Ephron (as opposed from taking the field for free, as Ephron offers), other than that the implication later is that because Abraham purchased Ma'arat HaMachpelah, no one can say that it does not belong to the Bnei Yisrael.

Translation of the passukim from [Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/63255/jewish/The-Bible-with-Rashi.htm). Text of the Midrash from [Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.79.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi).

Comment: Consider emphasising that the midrash does not say that this is why he did it, as the OP implied.

Comment: What about Samaria (Kings 1:16:24)?